# Python3 importing library with exec gives undefined variable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, import, exec

Here is my code for a server that allows remote importing of python3 libraries.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/import/<lib>",methods=['GET'])
def remote_import(lib):
    try:
        exec("import %s as m" % str(lib))
        fn = m.__file__
        with open(fn,"r") as f:
            return f.read(), 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "False", 404
app.run(host="127.0.0.1",port=5000)
```

It compiles and runs, but when testing (`curl http://localhost:5000/import/os`) I get "undefined variable 'm'".

Comment: Also [Dynamic module import in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/301134)

Comment: You should look up "importlib" in the docs. I would say never use exec, and most definately not when you have little/no control over its input.